# Escape quotes with IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I´m using IronPython to evaluate expressions written in python from within C#. The expression is to combine two strings: Foo + "Bar". Using `engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString` unfortunately eliminates the quotes so the result of this expression is FooBar rather then Foo"Bar". So how to escape the quotes before passing to `CreateScriptSourceFromString` to achieve this?

This is what I use so far:

```
engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("Foo + \"Bar\"")
```

EDIT: That results in a SyntaxErrorException because Python interprets Foo as variable... but should handle it as string-literal.

Comment: Did you try `\\"` (or `\"`)?  --> `engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("Foo" + "\\"Bar\\"");`

Comment: Have you tried `'"Bar"'` or `\"Bar\"`?

Comment: "Foo" + "\\"Bar\\"" won´t compile at all :(. Using \" results in what I posted before

Comment: You should put the `@` next to `""Bar\""`, not next to `"Foo"` as you're not escaping that string. --> `engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("Foo" + @"\"Bar\"")`

Comment: Does not compile neither. EDIT: I edited my source-code because my actual python-expression is Foo + "Bar". Now I get UnboundedNameException: "global name 'Foo' is not defined"

Comment: ***What*** is `Foo`?

Comment: I know that using this way Python thinks that Foo is a variable that might be appended by the string-instance "Bar". But how to avoid being interpreted as variable?

Comment: I'm with @Mati on this, if `Foo` isn't a variable, what is it supposed to be? A string literal?

Comment: A string literal, although I thought I expressed it clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working. The following did the trick (as far as I can estimate so far):
Hence the Python-engine expects a string for parsing I surrounded the actual expression into double-quotes. Thus Python recognizes `"Foo + \"Bar\""` rather then just `Foo + "Bar"` (which gives the exception mentioned above). So what I actually did was escaping the expression twice.

Thus we get the following snippet:

```
string expression = "Foo + \"Bar\"";
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
        "\"" + expression.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"");
object result = source.Execute();
```